# What happens to a parameter passed by value that is modified locally?

Tags: c++, c, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

I am well aware that modifying a function's argument that is passed by value is ineffective outside of the C/C++ function, but compilers allow it - but what happens?  Is a local copy made of the argument and that **is modifiable** within the function?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void doSomething( int x )
{
    x = 42;
    printf( "The answer to Life, the Universe and Everything is (always): %i!\n", x );
}

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    int a = 0;
    doSomething( a );
    return -a;
}
```

Now this always exits without error, but where in the scheme of things (memory space) is the value represented in the function as `x` kept?

I imagine that should the (combined declaration and definition) begin:

`void doSomething( const int x )`

I would get my wrists slapped by any half-decent compiler.

Comment: The function parameters are variables traditionally stored in the [call stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack).

Comment: Note: There exist no language called `C/C++`. In both of the languages, this expression invokes undefined behaviour. :)

Comment: Aaarrrghh, nobody (in their right mind) expects ___undefined behaviour___ but is it really?

Comment: @SlySven Well, having a side effect (increment-decrement) without a sequence point on a variable.....kaboom.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I don't think writing to a parameter is an undefined behavior.

Comment: @indiv: Can you provide a reference to any of the two different languages C or C++, where they require a call stack or at least define what that is?

Comment: @BlueWanderer: `C/C++` invokes indeed undefined behaviour. Reading `C` and modifying it are unsequenced and _If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined. ..._ (C standard, 6.5p2). Search yourself for C++.

Comment: It is not clear what your are asking actually. Your title already answers your question. Looks like you have a problem to understand what "pass-by-value" means,

Comment: @BlueWanderer :) you seem to have misunderstood the context, I was referring to `c/c++` expression, not the one in the question.

Comment: @Olaf:  There is one line in the question in particular asking for implementation details, so I provided a link to a traditional implementation.

Comment: @indiv: What is a "traditional implementation"? For VAX? 68000? PDP-11? Can't be a modern x64, because that uses registers to pass the first arguments and for other local variables. Can't be for MCUs, because there are some implementations which don't use a stack at all. That line simply makes the question too broad.

Comment: Um, is it possible someone mistook my use of `C/C++` to mean "what is the result of dividing value in a variable by the same post-incremented variable" when I meant it to mean "this is a question for both the C and C++ languages"? 8-P

Comment: They're just messing with you SlySven :) People on here are really allergic to seeing C and C++ in one sentence.

Comment: Oh, so they do not like how C++ enhances C but is built on top of it - in much the same way as WinDoze 95 et al. was built on top of Quick and Dirty Operating System... 8-P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the function `doSomething()`, `x` is local to the function. It has the similar scope of any other variable defined at the beginning of the function body.

In general terms, `x` exists only in the scope of `doSomething()` function. `x` is defined once `doSomething()` is called (and the argument is passed) and *destroyed* once the control returns. As long as the function call is being executed (i.e., the variable remains in scope), the parameter(s) are the same as any other variable, only initialized by the arguments supplied in the function call.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.1, *Scopes of identifiers*

> [...] If the declarator or type specifier that
>   declares the identifier appears inside a block or within the list of parameter declarations in
>   a function definition, the identifier has block scope, which terminates at the end of the
>   associated block. [...]

As you are already aware, `x` being the *local copy* of the actual argument passed to function call, any changes made to `x` inside the function will not *reflect* into the caller (actual argument), but there's no reason for the compiler to complain as long as the operation(s) on `x` inside the function is (are) valid.

Comment: But it exists as a ___variable___ that can be modified within the function?

Comment: @SlySven I have edited the answer to explicitly add that information, hope it's better in understanding now.

Comment: Yes - I've always made an explicit local copy of a passed argument if I intended to modify the value for use locally but perhaps I was being unduly paranoid and can save on such variable creation __provided I remember within the function, at a point of use of that variable, that it may not have the value it started with__!

Comment: Note: C does not require "destruction" once an object goes out of scope; there is just no destructor. Inot the scope & identifier are terminated (this is a compile-time thing). C++ as a different language has different rules.

Comment: @SlySven: Why do you care about premature optimisations? Concentrate on writing  **human readable** code. The compiler most likely knows better  how to optimise anyway.

Comment: I was not concerned about optimisations, It was more that I saw code modifying a parameter like this in a F.O.S.S. project I contribute to and I was trying to understand the rationale behind it - I am aware that code that modifies a (non-const) argument compiles but it does "smell" to me... 8-)

Answer (score 1):

As others have explained, `x` is local in function `doSomething`, any modifications only affect the local copy of the argument.

Note however that C++ allows passing by reference: a very small change in the definition of `doSomething()` would have significant consequences for this program:

```
void doSomething( int& x ) {
    x = 42;
    printf( "The answer to Life, the Universe and Everything is (always): %i!\n", x );
}
```

With the above function definition, variable `a` in `main` would indeed have its value changed to `42`. Since the code in `main()` is identical, this C++ feature can lead to confusing code, especially for a C programmer.

Comment: Guess, what - I started out as a C programmer but I have learnt that lesson - which is why one should use `void doSomething( const int &)` if passing by reference and you want to reassure the caller of `doSomething` that it won't clobber the referenced variable that it is given and the compiler doesn't need to/won't have to/does not make a copy of it... 8-)

Answer (score 0):

A value parameter of a function is effectively a local variable of the function, except that it is initialised in the function call. So these:

```
 void f( int n ) {
      n++;
   }
```

and:

```
 void g() {
      int n = 0;
      n++;
   }
```

are effectively the same, if the call to f() was made as f(0). In both cases, the variable will be discarded on function exit.

Comment: I should have used a non-zero value to the function call but I was trying to be clever and have a successful exit...

Comment: @Sly The value used to intialise it isn't important.

Answer (score 0):

The formal parameter `x` is a separate object in memory from the actual parameter `a`, so any changes to `x` are not reflected in `a`.

Comment: It might even not be in memory (but just in a register), at least for integers & pointers on AMD64 Linux API

Comment: I'd not refer to implementation details for such a question.

Answer (score -1):

Value x is local and is kept in stack. Each function has it own part of stack which is reserved when program enters function. 
Value x will be located in this part of stack. And it is valid only in scope of function which defined it.
If you change x it will be changed only for function where it is defined.
if function ends (return from function), stack which was reserved for function is destroyed so also value x. So x won't be accessible because it doesn't exists anymore.

Comment: There is no stack in any of the two languages C or C++.

Comment: @Olaf And how are function arguments passed into function? They are placed on stack. You can even check disassembly code and you will see `push` and `pop` instructions which are stack instructions.

Comment: Please provide a reference to thet standard (C or C++) where a stack is required to pass parameters. There are many other ways and C implementations exist which don't use a stack at all for typical code. Note: x86 is one of the least used platforms for C-programming (and most likely not the most common for C++ either).

Comment: ok I see what you mean. I thought that it can help to better understand what happen on background (in the most cases). It always helps to see under hood.

Comment: There are implementations which don't use a stack. Actually that's almost all 32 and 64 bit platforms.

Comment: Slight correction (too late to edit): "Actually that's almost all 32 and 64 bit platforms **for such a simple code**"